# Why doesn't implicit conversion from integer to byte work with the conditional operator?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for byte says that you can declare a byte like this:

```
byte myByte = 255;
```

and that

> In the preceding declaration, the integer literal 255 is implicitly
>   converted from int to byte. If the integer literal exceeds the range
>   of byte, a compilation error will occur.

So I'm struggling to understand why the following gives me a compile error of 'cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte')

```
byte value = on ? 1 : 0; // on is defined as a bool earlier
```

I'm compiling this on VS 2012 as a Windows Store App project, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is the problem with just using an explicit conversion?

Comment: Google for "C# ternary type" (without quotes).  The first few hits are SO answers, and all of them refer to Eric Lippert's blog or his SO answers which are pretty clear.  The best was (here)[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx].  The ternary will return an int, and you get no magic compiler help for converting that expression into a byte like you did with the earlier declaration.

Comment: This **would** work if `on` was a compile-time constant. For example, it works if you have `const bool on = true;`. Implict conversion from `int` to `byte` (narrowing) is not possible unless you have a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this:

```
on ? 1 : 0
```

Isn't an integer *literal*. It an expression that returns an integer. Moreover, this expression cannot be evaluated until runtime.

When there's a literal, the compiler can evaluate it at compile time and ensure it satisfies any range requirements - as the page says, it's up to the compiler to produce an error if the value is out of range.

And from your same [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You cannot implicitly convert non-literal numeric types of larger storage size to byte.

---

Per @Jeppe Stig Nielsen's comment - it does also work if the value is a constant (it doesn't have to be a literal as the first page says). C# spec says:

> **6.1.9 Implicit constant expression conversions**
>
> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following conversions:
>
> - A
>     constant-expression (§7.19) of type `int` can be converted to type
>     `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the
>     constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.
> - A
>     constant-expression of type `long` can be converted to type `ulong`,
>     provided the value of the constant-expression is not negative.